# vbs script with portable IE

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, portable-applications

I need your help in solving a problem.
I have this script,

```js
Dim IE
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1 
IE.Navigate "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&hl=it#identifier"
Do While (IE.Busy)
   WScript.Sleep 10
Loop
    With IE.Document
        .getElementByID("Email").value = "email"
  .getElementByID("signIn").click
    WScript.Sleep 500
  .getElementByID("Passwd").value = "password"
  .getElementByID("signIn").click
    End With
```

it works ok but with some IE versions it doesn't therefore I made an IE portable version and I save it on a usb flash.
Is it a way to force the script to use the portable IE ?
Moreover, how is it possible to uncheck the radio button 'Stay sign in' in gmail login ?

Thank you for your help

Bob